# Gravatar image not displaying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working through Michael Hartl's rails  tutorial and am currently trying to add a gravatar image to the user profile. The gravatar default image, however, does not load on my user show page.

**helpers/users_helper.rb**

```
module UsersHelper

  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1>
    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <%= @user.name %>

</h1>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I double checked the gravatar url,  but it still  does not seem to be loading. Tried restarting the server also. Not sure that the issue is?

Comment: Are You having any errors? update your question with `users_controller.rb` file.

Comment: Updated. Yes the gravatar image does now appear on my users show page.

Comment: Does the email you are providing have an account at [gravatar.com](https://en.gravatar.com/) ? if it's a new account, it may take a few minutes to be displayed.

Comment: Creating an account on the gravatar website necessary? The tutorial did not note this.

Comment: The email you provid must have an account on gravatar so you can render the custom image, if it's not registered in gravtar, it will provide the default images for you I prefer you to try with registered emails.

Comment: Still not working for me. I updated the user attributes with an email associated to a custom image but nothing renders on the page. As the default picture also fails to load, im assuming it's a seperate issue.

Comment: hmm... your code is correct but I assume may be its a css issue then try to set the `img-display to none`.

Comment: Thanks it was a css issue.  Turns out I had the previously set the image display to none but once i removed it, it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem is solved I have posted an answer please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct but Probably in one of your exercises in tutorial you write some custom class to hide images. Set the `image` class to `none`

```
image {
 display: none;
}
```

If its not the case then remove the `image-display` from `none`.

Answer (score 0):

What about `gravatar_for(@user)`

Looks like a method that needs to be passed a variable.

Comment: Using the instance varable will  give an error  because it isn't defined ifor the helper itself.However, I tried defining the instance in the helper but still the same issue. 'user' is also a defined variable in the database , so I don't believe the variable to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need gravatar ID in order to show your photo. In case that you don't want to open up new account on gravatar you can use the code below in your `users_helper.rb`:

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 180 })
    gravatar_id = 1
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

**NOTE** In case you open up gravatar account, you won't be able to remove your email address. Most users were complaining about this issue.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove the https: at the beginning of your gravatar_url string in your AvatarHelper module

```
module UsersHelper

  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```